# difference instantiation of android's button

Tags: android

i' m new on android, i want to know what are the differences to declare a button like :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    button = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button));
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

or

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    button = new Button(this);
    button.setId(..);
    button = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button));
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of differences are you interested in ? These 2 solutions have the same result.

Comment: @2Dee differences on the instatiation, what is the best to use instead other one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use first declaration, you have to define a button from xml. In the second one you are creating a button programmatically. You can also define it's position in the view etc.

Comment: thanks a lot, for the clarification, i have a question , in the second option i have to define the button properties into xml too?.

Comment: Nope if you use second one, you have to do all of declarations programmatically.

Comment: can i define the setOnclickListener by xml? so to avoid to implements by java code?

Comment: You can define like this; android:onClick="methodName" in xml, and then you can use methodName method from java part instead of setOnclickListener. If answer is useful please set as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the `Button in xml` then you should provide a `layout` to the `Activity` using [setContentView(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) and initialize the `Button` like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);//a button with id button should present in this layout
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

If you want to create a `Button` programmatically then you should do initialization like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
button = new Button(this);
button.setId(1);//some random integer value
setContentView(view);//some view
button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

[setContentView(View view) for 2nd case](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View))

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that

```
xml based layout is comparatively fast

xml based code at the end it converted in to java code by the compiler

and if you will use the second approach you have to do allot of things like setting the

width and height, position where it to be shown and by doing that

Your code will be messy

So it its better to use xml based layouts
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the second time you declare the button in the code. Then you add an id to it, presumably a new one. 
If you want to run the first code your button has to be declared in the xml layout resource file. This is the fastest way since it is optimized on the android framework to read the layouts from xml (it is actually converted to java, but in an optimized way). 
The second code does not require the layout file, although you do not add the button to a layout so the button as it is now is  not usable, as it is not 'on screen'.